# Flushing session when the user hits the 'Unlike' button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have an application which stores the signed_request in the session on initial load. The reason is to access the data without having to append `?signed_request` to all internal links.

I need to differentiate the view depending on if the user has `liked` the page or not.

Is there anyway I can bind an action, say an event handler that via ajax flushes my sessions? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding certain logic to my front page,

```
 13     if ( !isset( $_GET['fromnav'] ) ) {
 14         unset( $_SESSION['fb_data'] );
 15     }
 16 
 17     include 'includes/sess.php';
```

Any links that go to my index.php from within any navigation/internally need to be appended with ?fromnav. This states that its internal instead of a fresh state. If it's a fresh state, I clear the session fb data and parse the signature fresh. This seems to work so far.